# Android-Show Custom Dialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dialog

In my android application, I am using a custom dialog.  When I try to show the dialog, it causes an error.  I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I am really confused.

Here is my code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch(id) {
    case 0:
        dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.paused);
        dialog.setTitle("Game Paused");
        dialog.show();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is how I show the dialog

```
showDialog(0);
```

By the way, it says that showDialog(int) is deprecated.

Android logcat:

```
> 06-19 18:44:22.399: W/dalvikvm(467): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.jlennon.gametest.PlayGameActivity.pause(PlayGameActivity.java:105)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  ... 11 more
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at com.jlennon.gametest.PlayGameActivity.onCreateDialog(PlayGameActivity.java:131)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2472)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:881)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2547)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2514)
06-19 18:44:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(467):  ... 15 more
```

Thanks a whole lot in advance!

Comment: This method is deprecated. Use DialogFragment - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: That seems like to much code to be efficient.  Could I just call dialog.show()?  I tried this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes! Have a look at - http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  Dialog dialog;
  switch(id) {
   case 0:
    dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.paused);
    dialog.setTitle("Game Paused");
    dialog.show();
    break;
default:
    dialog = null;
}
return null;
```

}

I just replaced dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext()) to dialog = new Dialog(this);

Answer (score 2):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
dialog.show();
```

Instead of the code above.

I will use this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout,null,false);

dialog.setView(v);

dialog.show();
```

By the way, `onCreateDialog(int)` is deprecated;

Answer (score 2):

i have created a CustomDialog. like this..

[image]

the xml is ..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/createpost_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="CREATE POST"
            android:textColor="@color/mytextcolor"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/topic_ev"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/txt_field"
            android:hint="topic" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description_ev"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/destxt_field"
            android:hint="description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/upload_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/upload_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="UPLOAD A FILE JPEG,GIF OR PNG 3MB Max"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_forbuttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/createpost_layout"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/post_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/cancel_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and CustomDialogClass is

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.fragmentaltdd.R;

public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button Post, Cancel,Upload;

    public CustomDialogClass(Activity a)
    {
        super(a);

        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.createpost);

        Post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_btn);

        Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);

        Upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_btn);

        Post.setOnClickListener(this);

        Cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        Upload.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.post_btn:
              //c.finish();
                Toast.makeText(c, "Post button clikced", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              break;

            case R.id.upload_btn:
                 // c.finish();
                Toast.makeText(c, "Upload button clikced", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  break;

            case R.id.cancel_btn:
              dismiss();
              break;

            default:
              break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
    CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(getActivity());//while calling from fragment

CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(YourActivity.this);//while calling from Activity

            cdd.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using that method wrong. The point of the `createDialog` method is to, well, create the dialog and then return it. You're showing the dialog within the method, then not returning it at all, which defeats the purpose of overriding that method at all. You really should just have your own method that creates and displays your dialog.

Second of all, as AVD posted in the comments to your question, that method of displaying dialogs is deprecated for apps targeting an API for Honeycomb (11) or later.

Your problem, however, is that you're using the Application `Context` (`getApplicationContext()`) object to display a dialog that should belong to your `Activity`. You should pass in `this` instead to use the `Activity` context and that will fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;

new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this)
    .setTitle("Game Paused")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
    .show();
```

Comment: Read the OP. He/she is talking about custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> The Dialog class is the base class for creating dialogs. 
>       However, you typically should not instantiate a Dialog directly. 
>       Instead, you should use one of the following subclasses:
>
> AlertDialog
>
> ProgressDialog
>
> DatePickerDialog
>
> TimePickerDialog

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Google doesn't seems to give a reason for this on this document, or the actual API reference for the Dialog class. And as you already know, the error message doesn't either. So I'm not sure why the class is not 'protected'.

Anyway, using one of the above classes should solve your issue.

Please comment if anyone knows why we can't use the Dialog class directly.